# How to check if children are of a certain tag with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I'm trying to use **Puppeteer** to find prices from websites, and the way I'm doing it is running a `$$eval` and a set of if statements. I'm checking that there is a `"$"` in the `innerText` as well as a `children.length` of `0`. This works decently, but there are sometimes children for just part of the string (i.e. a bold `$` but a regular number). Is there any way to find out what tag the children are easily? I would like to check for no children having `<div>` tags. Below is my code:

```
var prices = await page.$$eval("div, span, p", (priceElements) => {
    var tmpPrices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < priceElements.length; i++) {
      const priceIndex = priceElements[i].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf("$");
      if (
        priceIndex > -1 &&
        priceElements[i].children.length == 0 &&
        priceElements[i].innerText.substring(priceIndex + 1).indexOf("$") == -1
      ) {
        tmpPrices.push(priceElements[i].innerText);
      }
    }
    return tmpPrices;
  });
```

And here's an example of when it doesn't work:

```
<div class="pricevalue1 accent-color1" style="font-size: 20px;">
   <b>
      <span class="currency-symbol">$</span>
      92,950
   </b>
</div>
```

Comment: `await` and callbacks? Use one of them.

Comment: It's a page function - basically it's like a way to run console code on the page through puppeteer. https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.6.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your specification, which seems to mention a few things that don't obviously relate from what I can tell. if you want to check that no div exists, why not simply `document.querySelector("div") === null`? What are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: In Puppeteer, I'm wanting to find all divs,spans,ps on a page and then check if their innerText contains a "$". If it has a "$" and it has no children then I want to include it (The reason for checking if there are no children is that there won't be duplicate values). However, sometimes there is a child like ```<b>$</b>``` that throws it off despite it being not really impactful to the value.